# Context/history on fibers, bundles and trivilizations in topology/differential geometry

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, soft-question, fiber-bundles

This is a soft-question in the sense that I have no confusion over the definitions of a bundle, fiber (see: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_bundle)), trivializing open sets and/or a locally trivial rank of $r$ (below are definitions for the latter two)

> A surjective smooth map $\pi:E\to M$ of manifoldsis said to be locally trivial of rank $r$ if i.) each fiber $\pi^{-1}(p)$ has a structure of a vector space of dimension $r$, ii.) for each $p \in M$ there are open sets $U$ of $p$ and a fiber-preserving diffeomorphism $\phi:\pi^{-1}(U)\to U\times \mathbb{R}^r$ s.t. $\forall q \in U$ the restriction $\phi\bigg|_{\pi^{-1}(q)}:\pi^{-1}(q)\to \{q\}\times\mathbb{R}^r$ is a vector space isomorphism. Such an open set $U$ is called a trivializing open set for $E$, and $\phi$ the trivialization of $E$ over $U$

But what I am interested in hearing is that what was/is the motivation i.) for the fibers/bundles/trivializations, ii.) to name the constructs the way they were? As a novice to both topology and differential geometry, the fibers/bundles etc. seem to come out of nowhere, so thinking the bigger picture, and the *why are we doing this* is rather difficult.

Comment: Are you only looking for the history? I would say that the naming of these objects are quite intuitive: A fiber bundle bundles fibers (a fiber is the preimage of a map at one point) in a continuous way and a trivialization makes the this bundling trivial in a small region.

Answer (score 2):

The book

> **History of Topology**, Elsevier, Amsterdam, 1999, Edited by I. James,

contains the article **Fibre Bundles, Fibre Maps** written by M. Zisman (it appears as chapter 22 on page 605 of James's volume). This article should include the information you are looking for.